# Jquery drill down menu item binding dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I need to fill the jquery drill down menu item dynamically from database.
In menu number of category has to be decide as per the data in the database

refereed from link : http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Mobile Phones &#038; Accessories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
                   <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Part A</a>
             <ul>  
                            <li><a href="#">Sale</a>  <ul>
```

I need this is to be fetch and display from the database, is there any way to implement ?

thanks 
suchith